# Normalizing the dependent variable in a multiple linear regression model

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression

What happens when I normalize the dependent variable but not the independent variables in a linear regression ? How will I interpret the model as opposed to normalizing both dependent and independent variables.

Thank You !!

Comment: What do you think is going to happen?

Comment: The X variables are still in raw data format, whereas the dependent variable Y will have mean=0 and std.dev=1. Therefore, a unit change in X will cause 1 std.dev. change in Y given by the beta coefficient of X ?

Comment: No, a unit change in the IV X (raw format) will cause beta change in the DV (which is standardized), so you can backtransform the beta into raw values. Just invert the standardization formula to get the x value out.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens when I normalize the dependent variable but not the independent variables in a linear regression ?

Nothing.

> How will I interpret the model as opposed to normalizing both dependent and independent variables.

If you normalize independent variables you will be able to compare/interpret weights of them after fitting.

Comment: It is still possible to de-normalize after fitting and then manually calculate fit statistics such as RMSE and R-squared.